# Merge identical rows of a CSV and generate a count value

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file with X and Y coordinates like-

```
X,Y
10,6
2,4
9,12
2,4
5,7
```

And so on.

I want to merge the common rows, and add another field that shows the count of each row like this-

```
X,Y,COUNT
10,6,1
2,4,2
9,12,1
5,7,1
```

How can I go about scripting this in Python 3? The file contains a few million rows, so are there any performance optimizations I can keep in mind?

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: If it's a big file, about the only thing you can really do is trade performance for memory. Iterate a file several times, processing only for some of the rows, writing all other rows as is and not writing duplicates, then reading file again and so on until there would be no rows left that are "written as is".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to do this would be to create a dictionary with the x and y as the key and a count.

Read the csv file in and process it like this:

```
csv_rows = [(1,2), (1,2), (2,4)]
coord_dict = {}
for row in csv_rows:
    if row in coord_dict:
        coord_dict[row] = coord_dict[row] + 1
    else:
        coord_dict[row] = 1
```

Would yield a list of coordinates as keys, with a value of the count:

```
>>> coord_dict
    {(1, 2): 2, (2, 4): 1}
```

The dictionary will grow proportionally to the number of unique coordinates in your csv file. If the amount of memory used causes a problem, consider breaking the input into chunks, or running multiple passes, each pass could process only a range of x co-ordinates, for example. I.e. pass one only processes x values between 0 and 5, pass two processes x values between 6 and 10, etc, etc. This would run slow, so that is your trade off. Multiple passes (slow), or single pass (large memory requirement).

Multiple pass example:

```
csv_rows = [(1,2), (1,2), (2,4)]
coord_dict = {}
for row in csv_rows:
    x, y = row
    if x >= 0 and x <= 5:
        # process the x values between 0 and 5 inclusive for this pass
        if row in coord_dict:
            coord_dict[row] = coord_dict[row] + 1
        else:
            coord_dict[row] = 1
    else:
        # skip for this pass
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the method. Would you advise using a dataframe (using pandas) for this situation?

Comment: No probs, gad to help. Personally I always try to keep things as simple as possible, so I would only bring pandas in if it was going to add something.

Comment: Just processed the file, and I didn't need to run multiple passes. It had 16 million records, only took a few seconds. Thanks once again!